# Sequence of holomorphic function and its derivative

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

> Let $f_n$ be a sequence of holomorphic functions in a domain $D\subset \mathbb C$.
>
> Let $f_n'$ be the sequence of the derivatives which converges compactly.
>
> And for a $z_0\in D,\ f_n(z_0)$ converges too. Show that  $f_n$ converges compactly.

**How I started**: $f_n(z_0)\to f(z_0)$ for $n\to\infty$, and because $f_n$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions, its limit $f$ will be holomorphic at $z_0$.

That means that $f_n'(z_0)$ converges compactly to $f'(z_0)$ since $f_n'$ converges to $f'$.

If $f_n$ is locally bounded then $f_n$ converges compactly.

How do I show that $f_n$ is locally bounded?

Comment: if $f_n'(z) \to g(z)$ [converges uniformly on every compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence), then $g(z)$ is holomorphic, by [Morera's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem) $\oint_\gamma g(z) dz = \lim_n \oint_\gamma f_n'(z) dz = 0$ for every closed contour $\gamma$ . Finally, write $$f_n(z) = f_n(z_0) +\int_{z_0}^z f_n'(s) ds$$ and that there is an holomorphic function $F(z)$ such that $F'(z) = g(z)$, so that $f_n(z_0) \to C \implies f_n(z) \to F(z)-F(z_0)+C$ uniformly on every compact

Comment: @user1952009 I dont understand the last step, why does $f_n(z)$ converges uniformly? And is $F(z)=f_n(z) (n\to\infty)$?

Comment: on any compact, the RHS converges uniformly to $C + \int_{z_0}^z g(z) dz = C + F(z)-F(z_0)$